# Is current provided by a transformer fixed?

Tags: transformer

I would like to connect a bell to a transformer as part of a project im working on. The only thing i cannot seem to find an answer to is wether or not the output from a transformer is fixed:

Say i was to plug a 24v 330ma step-down transformer into the bell (which operates at 24v 30ma), what would happen?:

A: The transformer overprovides, the bell takes everthing it's given and burns itself out.

B: Only the required amount of current is taken by the bell and everthing operates as normal.

C: Something else (?).

Comment: It's B. So many duplicates...

Comment: For that current, only the 30 mA will be drawn.

Comment: Duplicate of, for example, [Current input and output of transformer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/387268/current-input-and-output-of-transformer), and many others.

Comment: google `ohm's law`

Comment: Foundational: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/34745/2028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B, power supply is capable of providing more amps than the load requires.

Answer (score 1):

B is correct.

Thought experiment:

There's a (much bigger) transformer feeding your house. What happens if you switch off everything else except one little light bulb?

A: The transformer over-provides, the lightbulb takes everthing it's given and burns itself out.

B: Only the required amount of current is taken by the lightbulb and everything operates as normal.

C: The supply transformer explodes.